# Writing only final raster with intermediate bands going to disk using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst

I have a raster with 4 bands.

I would like to create a new raster (its individual bands called new_band) from this raster (its individual bands called old_band) in with :

```
new_band1 = old_band1 * 2
new_band2= old_band2 * 4
new_band3= old_band3 * 6
new_band4 = old_band4 * 8
```

My code is:

```
import sys, os, math, time
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("spatial")

raster = r"D:\IMAGERY.tif"
bands = [['band1', 2], ['band2',4],['band3',6],  ['band4', 8]]
outfolder =r"D:\Radiance"

for band in bands:
      num = band[0][4:]
      thisBand = raster + '\\band_' + num
      Radiance = arcpy.sa.Float(Raster(thisBand)/float(band[1]))
      outname = 'B' + num + '.tif'
      Radiance.save(os.path.join(outfolder,outname))
#and then combine different bands
  arcpy.CompositeBands_management("D:\Radiance\B1.tif;D:\Radiance\B2.tif;D:\Radiance\B3.tif;D:\Radiance\B4.tif", "D:\CANGIO\Anh_SOPT5\Radiance\compbands.tif")
```

In this code, I created both images for individual bands and a new raster.

As I just would like to create a new raster file, not rasters of individual bands, how can I do this?

Comment: Could you specify where you stuck and error messages that you receive?

Comment: I did not any error messages, it works but i would like to shorten my code which created each new individual bands and a new raster.  I just want to create only a new raster

Comment: can you use `in_memory` location to save your band info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment by @Surya, I think the way to accomplish what you are describing (i.e. make the final raster the only one written to disk) is to use an [in_memory workspace](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/the-in-memory-workspace.htm) to write the intermediate bands:

> Writing geoprocessing output to the in-memory workspace is an
>   alternative to writing output to a location on disk or a network
>   location.
>
> ...
>
> data written to the in-memory workspace is temporary and will be
>   deleted when the application is closed.
>
> ...
>
> Tables, feature classes, and **rasters** can be written to the in-memory
>   workspace.